# Dotplot of two random effects in one graph

Tags: r, lme4

If i make a simple mixed effects model with two random effects:

```
library(lme4)
(fm3 <- lmer(strength ~ 1 + (1 | batch) + (1 | sample), Pastes))
```

I can get acces to the random effects like so:

```
ranef(fm3)
ranef(fm3)$batch
ranef(fm3)$sample
```

I do not manage to plot the random effects in two separate dotplots next to each other.
The following bit of code does draw both plots but i do not manage recode it so that i can plot each graph separately:

```
dotplot(ranef(fm3, postVar=TRUE))
```

The following seems logical to me but it is not correct

```
dotplot(ranef(fm3, postVar=TRUE)$batch)
```

thanks for all help,

Comment: What package are you using ? I can't find the `dotplot` function in base R.

Comment: sory its part of `lattice` that loads automatically with `lme4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that `ranef()` stores the result of your analysis as a list, not data frame. You are trying to access this list as you would access data frame, that's why it doesn't work. The trick is to use double square bracket with `dotplot` to access the list. Then you can use `grid.arrange` to quickly combine your plots (or you can use @juba solution).

```
library(lme4)
fm3 <- lmer(strength ~ 1 + (1 | batch) + (1 | sample), Pastes)
d1 <- ranef(fm3, postVar=TRUE)
#double square bracket access the lists in d1
a <- dotplot(d1)[["batch"]]
b <- dotplot(d1)[["sample"]]
#grid.arrange combines your plots
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(a,b, nrow=1)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! both of our answers i think provide correct but slightly different approaches to the problem

Answer (score 2):

The following bit of code does the trick:

```
print((dotplot(ranef(fm3, postVar=TRUE))$sample), position=c(0, .5, 1, 1), more=TRUE)
print((dotplot(ranef(fm3, postVar=TRUE))$batch), position=c(0, 0, 1, .5)
```

It came from the realisation that plotting the prediction intervals for just one of the two rando effects can be done through:

```
(dotplot(ranef(fm3, postVar=TRUE))$sample)
```

and

```
(dotplot(ranef(fm3, postVar=TRUE))$batch)
```

What i proposed above is wrong (`dotplot(ranef(fm3, postVar=TRUE)$batch)` even though it does produce something).
@juba: thanks for pointing me towards lattice. the solution i found for combining plots is a bit more concise...

Answer (score 0):

As `dotplot` is part of the `lattice` package, you have to play with `grid.layout` and `viewports` to display several plots on one graph.

Here is a way to display two dotplots side by side, but as I'm quite new to `lattice` there surely is a better and cleaner way to do it :

```
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(0.25,0.5,.5,1))
print(dotplot(rnorm(100)),newpage=FALSE)
upViewport()
pushViewport(viewport(.75,.5,.5,1))
print(dotplot(runif(100)),newpage=FALSE)
```

Which gives :

[image]

Comment: this solution avoids some of the problems by introducing some random numbers to plot. see solution below

Comment: @agstudy As I said, I'm almost totally new to `lattice`, so thanks for pointing out my approximations...

Comment: Here it is question of grid package...e.g the accepted solution uses it through a wrapper of grid.layout in grid.extra package.